# Waiting for the method's return value

Tags: java

I am really a noob in java, so here's my problem.
I have a returned String:

```
public static String pushToServer(String data){
    //some code here
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            getResponse(); //accesing a public void method
    return string;
    }
```

The problem is, that `return string` code return null, because getResponse() method requests a couple of second to get the response. Any way to wait for getResponse() to finish and only then return String?

Comment: what does `getResponse()` method do? Post the code for it.

Comment: I would change getResponse so that it doesn't return until it has got the response.

Comment: getReponse() method just does a GET request, if server answers not ready, it waits 10 seconds and does another GET request.

Comment: well thats because u havent initialized the variable 'string' , give it some value then return

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try to use `Future` objects and `Callable` tasks. They are quite useful when you want to run some task in another thread and use returned data later. When you want to retrieve the operation results and the task has not finished your operation will simply block and wait until everything is ready to proceed. Here you can find how to use them: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial-callable.html

Simple example:

```
public class YourTask implements Callable {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        /* Do what you want to do */
    }
}
```

Somewhere in code:

```
Future future = yourThreadPool.submit(new YourTask());
```

Use the result:

```
String returnString = future.get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should using thread pool or FutureTask in another thread like this:

```
public static String pushToServer(String data){
    Future<V> f = getResponse(data)
    //waiting 10 second for the result at most
    return f.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


private Future<V> getResponse(data){   
    return athreadPool.submit(a task);
}
```